# Missing users from Keycloak Realm after import

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to import Realm Configuration and users into Keycloak.Realm is being imported fine but users are still missing even though keycloak-logs are printing that User are imported.

```
keycloak_1             | 12:33:31,635 INFO  [org.keycloak.exportimport.dir.DirImportProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Imported users from /opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/myrealm-users-0.json
keycloak_1             | 12:33:31,798 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) KC-SERVICES0032: Import finished successfully
```

Following is the configuraiton of docker-compose file.

```
keycloak:
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
    image: Keycloak_registry
    ports:
      - "31081:31081"
    volumes:
      - ./imports:/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_PROPS: -Dkeycloak.import=/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/fin4u-realm.json,/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/myrealm-users-0.json -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled -Dkeycloak.migration.action=import -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=          KEYCLOAK_ADDITIONAL_PROPS: -Dkeycloak.import=/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/myrealm-realm.json,/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports/myrealm-users-0.json -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled -Dkeycloak.migration.action=import -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=IGNORE_EXISTING/opt/jboss/keycloak/imports -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=IGNORE_EXISTING
      HOSTNAME: localhost
      CERTBASE: localhost
      HTTPS_PORT: 38081
      KEYCLOAK_JGROUPS_PORT: 9000
```

So In above yaml code, it can be seen that Realm Configuration and Users are target to be imported. Realm got imported successfully but users are still missing even though logs are showing that users are imported too.

Answer (score 2):

The following suggestions are tested for Keycloak 16.1.1 ([jboss/keycloak image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/)) and based on the [Importing and exporting the database](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#assembly-exporting-importing_server_administration_guide) chapter from the official Keycloak docs.

### Using correct import parameters

The documentation states that:

> You cannot use the `keycloak.import` parameter with `keycloak.migration.X` parameters. If you use these parameters together, Keycloak ignores the `keycloak.import` parameter. The `keycloak.import` mechanism ignores the realms which already exist in Keycloak. The `keycloak.import` mechanism is convenient for development purposes, but if more flexibility is needed, use the `keycloak.migration.X` parameters.

Therefore, I used solely the `keycloak.migration.X` options in the following solution.

### Naming convention

As we can read in the docs:

> When importing from a directory, the filenames must follow this naming convention:
>
> - <REALM_NAME>-realm.json. For example, "acme-roadrunner-affairs-realm.json" for the realm named "acme-roadrunner-affairs".
> - <REALM_NAME>-users-<INDEX>.json. For example, "acme-roadrunner-affairs-users-0.json" for the first user’s file of the realm named "acme-roadrunner-affairs".

In my example project I have the `keep-growing` realm. Therefore, the import files are named: `keep-growing-realm.json` and `keep-growing-users-0.json`.

### Volume

My example volume config from the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
  keycloak:
    …
    volumes:
      - ./keycloak/realms/import:/tmp/import
    …
```

The `./keycloak/realms/import` on my machine contains:
[image]

As a result, after restarting the docker instance, I can see all the files from the aforementioned location on my machine available in the container:
[image]

### Minimal import config

I added the following commands to my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
  keycloak:
    …
    volumes:
       …
    command:
      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import"
      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir"
      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/tmp/import"
```

This will import the realm on the container startup and overwrite the existing one (if one already exists).

### Recreate the container to test the import

I deleted the container and started it again. The users were imported properly:
[image]

### Verify logs

As we can see in the problem description, logs are not a guarantee that the export was successful. However, I decided to include here the entries that I received after starting the container:

```
INFO  [org.keycloak.exportimport.dir.DirImportProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Importing from directory /tmp/import
…
INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) KC-SERVICES0050: Initializing master realm
INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) KC-SERVICES0030: Full model import requested. Strategy: OVERWRITE_EXISTING
INFO  [org.keycloak.exportimport.util.ImportUtils] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Realm 'keep-growing' imported
INFO  [org.keycloak.exportimport.dir.DirImportProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) Imported users from /tmp/import/keep-growing-users-0.json
INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) KC-SERVICES0032: Import finished successfully
```

### For reference

The complete `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:${KEYCLOAK_VERSION}
    ports:
      - "8024:8080"
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./keycloak/realms/import:/tmp/import
    command:
      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import"
      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir"
      - "-Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/tmp/import"
```

The `.env` file:

```
KEYCLOAK_VERSION=16.1.1
KEYCLOAK_USER=keycloak
KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=keycloak
```

EDIT: I wrote more on Keycloak directory import in the [Keycloak in Docker #6 - How to import realms from a directory](https://keepgrowing.in/tools/keycloak-in-docker-6-how-to-import-realms-from-a-directory/) post.